# Turning on/off regex modifiers in Python

Tags: python, regex

Although some programming languages such as PHP allow modifiers to be turned on/off part way through a regex command [e.g. using `(?-i)`], so the modifier only applies to part of the command, both the standard `re` module, and the newer alternative `regex` module do not seem to allow this (and throw up an error if included).

Is there any work around for this - for example a modified version of regex which does allow turning off modifiers?

Comment: you could always split your string into substrings and preform different regexes on the substrings then concatenate them but yeah that sounds ugly

Comment: No, Python re module does not allow that operation. These inline modifiers modify the behavior of the whole regex pattern, not just part of it.